# php preg_match - match characters between [POLYLINE] and [END]

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

To my shame, i know not how to use regular expressions properly. I have a large text file, and i am interested in matching every occurence of strings between the tags [POLYLINE] and [END]. The structure does not nest, meaning i do not have other [POLYLINE] and [END] tags inside other [POLYLINE] and [END]. I have tried :

```
preg_match_all('/\[POLYLINE\](.*?)\[END\]/', $fileContents, $matches);
```

Hoping to get an array of strings inside $matches. This returns something, but not what i need.

Comment: `This returns something, but not what i need.` -- what is the result you're getting and what is the result you need?

Answer (score 2):

Add `s` flag for DOTALL functionality which will make it match across multiple lines:

```
preg_match_all('/\[POLYLINE\](.*?)\[END\]/s', $fileContents, $matches);
```

Comment: [It works](https://eval.in/79071) without the `s` flag. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @AmalMurali: See this demo: https://eval.in/79073 It doesn't match because start tag and end tags have newlines between them. Now see same code with `s` flag: https://eval.in/79074